# Populate DataTable with data from MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

I am trying to populate my Datatable with data from MySQL but can't figure out how to do so. I want to be able to populate the DataTable once directed to the page, then user can click on a row and use that row's data for the next page the user will be redirected to. This is what I have so far:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>

        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>

</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
    </tr> 
</tfoot>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td> Placeholder1</td>
        <td> Placeholder2</td>
        <td> Placeholder3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Placeholder1</td>
        <td> Placeholder2</td>
        <td> Placeholder3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Placeholder1</td>
        <td> Placeholder2</td>
        <td> Placeholder3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script>


$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var data = table.row( this ).data();
    alert( 'You clicked on '+data[0]+'\'s row' );
} );
} );
</script>
```

PHP FILE:

```
<?php

include('connection.php');



 $sql = "SELECT ID, Name, Age, Gender FROM DBTABLE";


$response = mysqli_query($db, $sql);


if($response)
{
    echo '<table>';

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response))
    {

       echo '<tr><td align="left">' .
            $row['Name'] . '</td><td align="left">' .
            $row['Age']  '</td><td align="left">' .
            $row['Gender'] . '</td><td align="left">';


       echo '</tr>';
    }

   echo '</table>';

  }
else
{
    echo "Couldn’t issue database query<br />";
    echo mysqli_error($db);
}






// Close connection to the database
mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: You initialized the wrong one.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/pandeyz/Jquery-Datatable---Server-Side-with-Custom-Inline-Editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the dataTables API instead

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: 'phpfile.php'
  },
  columns: [
    { data: 'Name' },
    { data: 'Age' },
    { data: 'Gender' }
  ]
});
```

phpfile.php

```php
...
$data = array();
if ($response) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response)) {
    $data[] = $row;
  }
}
echo json_encode(array('data' => $data));
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I'm sure this works too but I think I figured out a solution of just passing the the data from the row by passing it through the URL into a PHP GET variable.